# Regex replace spaces at each new lines

Tags: swift, regex, nsregularexpression

I am saving users input to db as a string and I would like to remove all spaces at each lines.

Input from user:

```
Hi!

My name is:
   Bob

I am from the USA.
```

I want to remove spaces between "Bob", so the result will be:

```
Hi!

My name is:
Bob

I am from the USA.
```

I am trying to do it with the following code

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\n[\\s]+", options: .caseInsensitive)
a = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: a, options: [], range: NSRange(0..<a.utf16.count), withTemplate: "\n")
```

but this code replace multiple new lines "\n", I don't want to do it.
After I run the above code: `"1\n\n\n    2"` -> `"1\n2"`. The result I need: `"1\n\n\n2"` (only spaces  are removed, not new lines).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?m)^\\h+", options: .caseInsensitive)
```

Actually, as there are no case chars in the pattern, you may remove `.caseInsensitive` and use:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?m)^\\h+", options: [])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMnJQv/1). The pattern means:

- `(?m)` - turn on multiline mode
- `^` - due to `(?m)`, it matches any line start position
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespaces.

Swift code example:

```swift
let txt = "Hi!\n\nMy name is:\n   Bob\n\nI am from the USA."
let regex = "(?m)^\\h+"
print( txt.replacingOccurrences(of: regex, with: "", options: [.regularExpression]) )
```

Output:

```
Hi!

My name is:
Bob

I am from the USA.
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for regex, split the string on the new line character into an array  and then trim all lines and join them together again

```
let trimmed = string.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    .map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) }
    .joined(separator: "\n")
```

or you can use `reduce`

```
let trimmed = string.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
    .reduce(into: "") { $0 += "\($1.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))\n"}
```